# Is there a way to forbid object members declaration in inherited classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, member

I need to construct a specialized object, that uses the base class constructor.
This will happen in a template method, so the constructed object will be one of the specialized classes I created.

Let's say we have classes: Base, Child1, Child2, Child3.

```cpp
template <class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> createObject(...) {

...

return std::make_shared<T>(arg X, arg Y);
}
```

I want this method to return object of classes `Child1`, `Child2` or `Child3`. Therefore, I am using a the `Base` class constructor `Base(arg X, arg Y)`.

The problem is that if I a have a object member in one of these classes, it might not be initialized when constructed using the base class.

Example:

```cpp
struct A{
    A() = default;
    int a{1};
    int b{2};
};

struct B:public A{
    B(int val):c{val}{};
    using A::A;
    int c{3};
};

int main(){
    auto b_obj = std::make_shared<B>();
    return b_obj->c;
}
```

Using MSVC, the `b_obj` construction didn't initialize the `int c` object member.

Therefore, to avoid this bug-prone behaviour, I was wondering if there is a way to forbid object member declaration in inherited classes, for instance.

Or if there is a different approach to what I need, to avoid errors.

Comment: You aren't constructing anything using the base class in this example. You're constructing B using B, and B's code has a bug in it.

Comment: Don't pull in the default constructor from A, or explicitly delete the default constructor from B. In fact, you should be doing that anyways. Define all or none.

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](https://rextester.com/WCI99768), the code doesn't compile with Visual Studio because `B` has no default constructor

Comment: `to avoid this bug-prone behaviour` if this really happens, this is compiler bug, not yours.

Comment: @KamilCuk Why is it a compiler bug?